# How do I fill this Boolean hole? I have already applied Boolean operation

Tags: modeling

[image]

I made these holes on a curved part of the body using boolean and array modifiers. Both have been long applied which was my mistake. How do i fill these holes?

Comment: In Edit mode, go to Edge or Vertex mode and Alt-click on the edge of the face round the hole. That should select the whole rim and you can try using 'F' to fill the hole. You'll have to do this for each side of the object of course. Then use Mesh > Limited Dissolve to remove the extra edges that you no longer need.

Comment: Hi, Taif.  Please edit this question to show us the topology of your model, ideally from further out, so we can get context. Or better yet, share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ , Without those, we really can't answer your case, specifically.

Comment: Thank you my friend for suggestion. I'm reworking on the model. Thanks.